# Can't change default text width in GVim

Tags: vim, vimrc, gvim

Gvim is set to 78, can't change default text width to "0" at gvim, i edited  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim_vimrc" `set textwidth=0` or `set tw=0` but neither helped. How do i disable textwidth parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you are testing the feature.  According to the documentation,

> [`textwidth`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27textwidth%27) `'tw'`    *number*    (default 0)
>               local to buffer
>               {not in Vi}
>   Maximum width of text that is being inserted.  A longer line will be
>       broken after white space to get this width.  A zero value disables
>       this.  `'textwidth'` is set to 0 when the **'paste'** option is set.  When
>       `'textwidth'` is zero, `'wrapmargin'` may be used.  See also
>       `'formatoptions'` and `|ins-textwidth|`.
>       When `'formatexpr'` is set it will be used to break the line.
>       **NOTE:** This option is set to 0 when **'compatible'** is set.

Presumably you didn't set `compatible`, but may have set `paste`.  Alternatively, there may be some plug-in which is resetting the value.
Or you could be expecting setting `textwidth` to affect already-entered text:

- [VIM textwidth has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136902/vim-textwidth-has-no-effect)

According to

- [textwidth=0 and wrapwidth=0 in .vimrc.local not being respected](https://superuser.com/questions/250112/textwidth-0-and-wrapwidth-0-in-vimrc-local-not-being-respected)

you can see where it's set using

```
:verbose set tw? wm?
```

The [answer by @garyjohn](https://superuser.com/a/250116/441480) gives additional advice on troubleshooting this problem.

Comment: woow thanks a lot, :verbose option helped, there was  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\vimrc_example.vim"  extra vimrc file, which had priority over. sorry can't upvote, not 15 yet :)